# SQL Update statement is not run as expected

Tags: sql, sql-server

there are 2 tables in sql server, one is s1 and one is s2, both of them just contain id and name filed and the data in the two tables are like this:

```
id          name
----------- --------------------
1           a
2           b

(2 row(s) affected)

id          name
----------- --------------------
1           A
1           B
1           C

(3 row(s) affected)
```

the update statement is like this :

```
update s1 set name = g.name from s1 d, s2 g
  where d.id = g.id
```

after run the update statement, I check s1 table and the result is like this:

```
id          name
----------- --------------------
1           A
2           b
```

I was confused by this result, can anybody tell me why ? in my opinion, I think this should throw an exception because there are more than one row returned for the update

Comment: What should be really updated? what is your expected result? tell that we can fix it

Comment: Exception will be throw for this data when you are using sub-query to update

Comment: your id in s2 table is all '1', change it to unique values to 1, 2, 3 and your query will work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean by "unexpected".  You have matching condition between two tables, and multiple rows in the second table match each row in the first table.

SQL Server chooses an arbitrary matching row for the update.  This is *clearly* explained in the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177523.aspx):

> Use caution when specifying the FROM clause to provide the criteria
>   for the update operation. The results of an UPDATE statement are
>   undefined if the statement includes a FROM clause that is not
>   specified in such a way that only one value is available for each
>   column occurrence that is updated, that is if the UPDATE statement is
>   not deterministic. For example, in the UPDATE statement in the
>   following script, both rows in Table1 meet the qualifications of the
>   FROM clause in the UPDATE statement; but it is undefined which row
>   from Table1 is used to update the row in Table2.

Also, you should write your query using explicit `JOIN` syntax:

```
update s1
    set name = g.name
    from s1 d join
         s2 g
         on d.id = g.id;
```

I don't believe that any database gives an error in this case.  In terms of the underlying engine, it is a bit tricky to figure out if a row is being updated multiple times.

Comment: thanks for your comments, it let me understand some conceptions

Answer (score 1):

The results of this are undefined because the join produces 3 rows for `id = 1`, all of which are candidates for the update. SQL Server will not treat the multiple rows as an error like it would for (say) a subquery, however you probably want to avoid this behavior.

Comment: so, my wondering is the name was updated by 'A' but not 'B' or 'C'? do you know why?

Comment: It will update with first value in the underlying base table

Comment: do you know why 'A' is the last value, is there a mechanism for SQL server to decide which value should be the last one in underlying base table? another question is what is underlying base table?  is it S2?

Comment: It's undefined (see Gordon's answer). The actual order will depend on what index SQL Server chooses to use to read the data. Remember that SQL is a declarative set-based language and there is no concept of "first" unless you explicitly define it via an ORDER BY.

Answer (score 0):

No it doesnt  throw exception. what happens ?

it looks for the IDs matching 1 in s2 and it will set the first matching ID it finds to s1.name.

and the rest is so clear when it cant find 2 it doesnt change anything ;)